# @XmlElement(required=true) for @WebParam does not work

Tags: java, annotations, jax-ws, required

I'm building web service using JAX-WS. I have a strange problem that the annotation `@XmlElement(required=true)` for `@WebParam` works in some `@WebService` class, but doesn't work in some others.

I have very similar code in the two `@WebService` classes. What may cause this problem? Parameter type or the entity class?

**Edit: Add sample code**

I have two web services:

```
@WebService(name = "ClubMemberPortType", serviceName = "ClubMemberService", portName = "ClubMemberSoapPort", targetNamespace = "http://club.com/api/ws")
public class ClubMemberWS {
@WebMethod(operationName = "findClubMembersByClubId", action = "urn:findClubMembersByClubId")
    @WebResult(name = "club_membership")
    public List<ClubMembership> findClubMembershipsByClubId(@XmlElement(required=true)
                                                        @WebParam(name = "club_id") String clubId, 
                                                        @WebParam(name = "status") StatusEnum status){
...
}}
```

and

```
@WebService(name = "ClubPortType", serviceName = "ClubService", portName = "ClubSoapPort", targetNamespace = "http://club.com/api/ws")
public class ClubWS {
@WebMethod(operationName = "findClubByClubId", action = "urn:findClubByClubId")
    @WebResult(name = "club")
    public Club findClubByClubId(@XmlElement(required=true)
                                @WebParam(name = "club_id") String clubId) {
...
}}
```

The generated schema for the first web method is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://club.com/api/ws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:findClubMembersByClubId>
         <club_id>?</club_id>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <status>?</status>
      </ws:findClubMembersByClubId>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The generated schema for the second web method is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://club.com/api/ws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:findClubByClubId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <club_id>?</club_id>
      </ws:findClubByClubId>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So the first one works fine, the second one does not work. How is it possible? :(

Comment: Any code samples for the two cases? Actual problem you are facing (e.g. exceptions, better description of the behavior, etc)?

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of the error

Comment: When I add @XmlElement get ERROR `The annotation @XmlElement is disallowed for this location`   e.g `public boolean validateRegistration(@XmlElement(required = true) @WebParam String devicedId`.   Java 1.6.45

Comment: Correct answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211420/xmlelement-annotation-dissallowed-with-webparam

Answer (score 5):

Adding `@XmlElement(required=true,nillable=false)` after `@WebParam` solved my similar problem. Using CXF 2.7.9. Did not try putting `@XmlElement` first, could it be that simple?

Comment: Getting The annotation `@XmlElement is disallowed for this location` . How to solve this issue . Using RSA for development. If i need to update cxf version , Kindly help with maven link with version

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem. I found solution in using of separate class for parameters of service method.

e.g.

```
@XmlType(name="SampleRequestType", propOrder={"title", "ref"})
public class SampleRequest {
    @XmlElement(name="title", required=false)
    private String title;
    @XmlElement(name="ref", required=true)
    private String ref;
    ...
```

web-method

```
@WebMethod
public String sampleMethod(@WebParam(name = "params") SampleRequest params) {
```

maybe this will help

Comment: If we do in this way, 'SampleRequestType' itself shows optional.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having the following error message: "***The annotation @XmlElement is disallowed for this location***", chances are you're using the wrong import statement.

Change it to:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
```

As Eclipse suggests another package as the first option, it's a very common mistake.

Comment: For that one I have `@XmlElement not applicable to parameter`

Answer (score 0):

You try change the order in @WebParam and @XmlElement? actually i have a WS whit this:

```
public Persona consultarPersona(@WebParam(name = "cedula") @XmlElement(required=true, nillable=false, name="cedula", namespace="cedulaParam")  String cedula)
```

And the description generate is:

```
 <xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="cedulaParam" schemaLocation="http://eniacstein-pc:8080/WSDL_Sample/GestorPersonas?xsd=2"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

and the schema definition:

```
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" targetNamespace="cedulaParam">
<xs:element name="cedula" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

that's it!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I found the solution. If anyone encounters the same problem, just place these annotations in you web service contract(interface) in exact this order, as all guys answered before.

```
@WebParam(name = "yourParam") @XmlElement(required = true)  YourParam param
```

Comment: The order appears to be irrelevant (tested against CFX 3.4.2).  @XmlElement(required = true) does indeed the job, probably depending on CXF's databinding (JAXB 2.x by default). Talking about job done: You need to turn on schema verification (default off) to let CFX check for the correct number of arguments. Otherwise all you get is a proper WSDL type definition.