# Type or param of web-service method marked in WSDL as non-nullable

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

How to make type that will marked in WSDL as non-nullable?

if the above is impossible, How to describe param of web-service method that it will marked in WSDL as non-nullable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the below articles for details
[Making a web service request parameter a required field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071772/making-a-web-service-request-parameter-a-required-field)
[How can I make a WebMethod parameter required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210346/how-can-i-make-a-webmethod-parameter-required)
[XmlElement annotation dissallowed with WebParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211420/xmlelement-annotation-dissallowed-with-webparam)
To put it simply, you need to use the `@XmlElement(required=true)` for more details refer to the above posts.