# How to make a parameter required in soap webservices?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

How can I make a parameter required for a `soap` webservice?

```
@WebService
public class MyService {
    //how can I make city param required?
    @WebMethod
    public ComplexResponse lookup(@WebParam(name = "city") String city) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding

```
@XmlElement(required=true, nillable=false)
```

to the param should work:

```
public ComplexResponse lookup(@WebParam(name = "city") @XmlElement(required=true, nillable=false) String city)
```

Comment: great, I was not aware one can use `@XmlElement` within the method signature.

Comment: Note that it requires JAX-B 2.2+. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211420/xmlelement-annotation-dissallowed-with-webparam