# Not able to make @webparam mandatory field JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-ws

I am trying to make my `@webparam` mandatory using `(@XmlElement(required=true)` but the generated XSD still shows this as `minOccurs="0"`. Also tried setting `nillable=false` but still not working.

Here is my web method :

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "Biller")
public Biller getBiller(@XmlElement(required=true) @WebParam(name = "billerId") Integer billerId){}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869494/xmlelementrequired-true-for-webparam-does-not-work

Comment: Tried all these steps , still facing same issue.

Comment: what's your cxf version?

Comment: its 2.6.1. Also added @EndpointProperties(value = { @EndpointProperty(key = "schema-validation-enabled", value = "true") }) in my Web service class

Comment: Tried adding @SchemaValidation(enabled=true), still no scuccess.

Comment: and does your  xsd become correct if you change `Integer biller` to `int biller` ( primitive int ) ?

Comment: @SabirKhan when I changed parameter to primitive int , the xsd is like
<xs:complexType name="getBiller">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="billerId" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

Also in the request XML in SOAPUI I can see optional comment as removed. but if i remove the element API call still works fine. and what if my webparam is of String or any other Wrapper type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by me in comments - either you need to wrap your `Integer` variable into some Java POJO and apply rules for specific fields in that POJO or change to primitive type because - reference types are always optional but constituent fields of wrapper types can be made required or optional. 
Primitive types are always required.

[Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2214848/3850730)

Then comes the question about default values - and for that refer [Answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821477/xml-schema-minoccurs-maxoccurs-default-values) and summary is - if nothing is specified -

> minOccurs and maxOccurs default to 1

Now why your call succeeds with SOAP UI - Your xsd is correct and that is acknowledged by SOAP UI so my guess is client might be attaching some default values when its missing. I haven't used SOAP UI. Try examining your request ans see if value is really missing. If value is indeed missing in request then try to examine as why validation is not kicking in.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer, SOAP UI started validating my request against XSD schema when I added @com.sun.xml.ws.developer.SchemaValidation to my Web service class . But now I am getting com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.soap.DeserializationException for response which I am trying to figure out. Thanks agian :)